# /*jshint esversion: 6 */ alternative method

Tags: atom-editor, jshint

At the top of all .js files (in atom editor) i have to add the following code:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
```

otherwise i get w104 lint warnings for any "const declarations". Is there a global setting to remove this ? or what is the best method ?